# What are all the valid SystemCapabilities keys possible usually generated by Xcode?

Tags: xcode6, rubymotion

I do not use Xcode to build my IPA. I tried searching apple documentation, but I cannot find what the key values are for all possible system capabilities. In order to not be lazy, I also tried to archive a project with these capabilities turned on, and searched through the IPA, but cannot find where `Xcode6` is hiding these entitlements.

For users using Xcode6 these are the capabilities listed here

[image]

Since I generate my IPA manually, I need to know what these keys are in order to match the capabilities set on my App Identifier.

**UPDATED**

Here are the key values, they were actually in the `project.pbxproj` file, thanks for the help @colinta

```
SystemCapabilities = {
  com.apple.ApplicationGroups.iOS = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.BackgroundModes = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.DataProtection = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.GameCenter = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.HealthKit = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.HomeKit = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.InAppPurchase = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.InterAppAudio = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.Keychain = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.Maps.iOS = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.OMC = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.Passbook = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.SafariKeychain = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.VPNLite = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.WAC = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
  com.apple.iCloud = {
    enabled = 1;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your screenshot gave me an idea - check the diff of the project.pbxproj file!  Came up with this:

```
+ SystemCapabilities = {
+   com.apple.GameCenter = {
+     enabled = 1;
+   };
+   com.apple.InAppPurchase = {
+     enabled = 1;
+   };
+ };
```

HTH